# How does multi-texture OBJ->JSON converted files keeps track of face-texture mapping?

Tags: json, load, three.js, webgl, textures

I'm trying to manually (no libs such as Three.js) load a JSON 3D model into my webGL code just for fun but I'm having a hard time when my models have more than 1 texture.
In a OBJ->JSON converted file, how do I know which texture is the "active" for the faces that follow? OBJ files use 'usemtl' tag to identify the texture/material in use but I can't seem to find that kind of pointer when working with JSONs.
In time, I'm using the OBJ->JSON converter written by [alteredq](https://github.com/alteredq)

Thanks a bunch,
Rod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this file: `three.js / src / extras / loaders / JSONLoader.js`.

The first element of each face in the `faces` array of the JSON file is a bit field. The first bit says if that face have three o four indices. And the second bit says if that face has a material assigned. Material index, if any, appears after indices.

Example: `faces: [2, 46, 44, 42, 0, 1, 45, 46, 48, 3, ...`

First face (triangle with material):

```
Type: 2 (00000010b)
Indices: 46, 44, 42
Material index: 0
```

Second face (quad without material):

```
Type: 1 (00000001b)
Indices: 45, 46, 48
```

Third face (quad with material):

```
Type: 3 (00000011b)
Indices: ...
```

Check source code for full meaning of that bit field.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for the answer, Juan.

Comment: Just as a matter of clarification, wouldn't that field be a "byte field"? A "bit field" would hold 1 bit giving only 2 possibilities, 0 or 1. Nevertheless very helpful answer, thanks.

Comment: @rod No, "bit field" is ok. See Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).

Comment: Did not know that. Yet another new thing I learned today :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In the OBJ->JSON converter I have written for the KickJS game engine, each material has its own range of indices.

This means a simple OBJ model such as

```
    mtllib plane.mtl
    o Plane
    v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
    v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
    v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
    usemtl Material
    s 1
    f 2 3 4
    usemtl Material.001
    f 1 2 4
```

Would be translated into this (With two indices; one for each material):

```
    [
       {
          "vertex": [1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,-1,1,0,-1],
          "name": "Plane mesh",
          "normal": [0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0],
          "indices0": [0,1,2],
          "indices1": [3,0,2]
       }
    ]
```

Use the online model viewer for the convertion:

http://www.kickjs.org/example/model_viewer/model_viewer.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, mortennobel. The link you provided seems broken, though. All I can see are the buttons (Duck, Cube, Teapot, etc) nothing else.

Comment: There is currently an issue with Firefox. Try Chrome (while I fix the Firefox issue)

Comment: Issue fixed. Thanks for the feed back. I hope my tool interesting.